# Flowchart Draw with squared connections

Tags: latex, flowchart

I try to draw a diagram on the provided link from the "act" to the decision diamond up on the beginning of the flow chart, but I fail. I would like to draw a connection arrow from block to the diamond without crossing the other blocks. Could someone help me to do it?

https://www.overleaf.com/1327913296kgkmkvmhqgmj

Best regards
Bruno

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood weel, maybe adding some hidden nodes may be of some help:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}

\input{config}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[!htp]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 2cm, auto]
        % Place nodes
        \node [cloud] (init) {Initialize};
        \node [block, left of = init, node distance = 4cm] (estimate) {Estimate};
        \node [block, below of = estimate, node distance = 3cm] (compute) {Compute};    
        \node [decision, below of = init] (decide_exploration) {$t \in (t_i, \, t_{i+1})$?};
        \node [decision, below of = decide_exploration, node distance = 4cm] (decide_sample) {$t_s \in (t_s^0, \, t_s^0 + T_s)$?};
        \node [block, right of = decide_sample, node distance = 4cm] (sample) {Sample};
        \node [block, below of = decide_sample, node distance = 4cm] (control) {Act};
        \node [below of = control, node distance = 2cm] (control2) {};
        \node [right of = control2, node distance = 6cm] (control3) {};
        \node [right of = decide_exploration, node distance = 2cm] (sample2) {};

        % Draw edges
        \path [line, dashed] (init) -- (estimate);
        \path [line] (estimate) -- (compute);
        \path [line] (compute) |- (control);
        \path [line] (decide_exploration) -- node {yes} (decide_sample);
        \path [line] (decide_exploration) -- node {no} (estimate);
        \path [line] (decide_sample) -- node {yes} (control);
        \path [line] (decide_sample) -- node {no} (sample);
        \path [line] (sample) |- (control);
                \path [line] (control) |-(6,-13) |-(sample2) |-(decide_exploration);

    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Source seeking algorithm}
    \label{fig:sseeking_algo}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

I used some funny names for the hidden nodes, you may find something more significant..

EDIT: I edited the last line, so the corner is not missing anymore.

Comment: The funnier, the better

Comment: If not too nitty-picky, how could I connect the bottom-edge of the connection?